# PHP Query To Filter Many-To-Many MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, filter

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Names FROM all_uk
INNER JOIN cat_uk ON all_uk.Ref = cat_uk.Ref
INNER JOIN res_uk ON all_uk.Ref = res_uk.Ref
WHERE (cat_uk.Cat_Ref IN (25, 35)) AND (res_uk.Res_Ref = 1) AND (res_uk.Res_Ref = 2)
```

As you can see, the first part of the `WHERE` query is cumulative (everything that has either a 25 or a 35 ref). The second part is where I'm failing: I want to restrict the results to those where they have 1 AND a 2 in their second category.

Selecting one of these (i.e. either 1 OR 2) returns results, but when they're both selected I get nothing.

Can anyone help?

Comment: res_uk.Res_Ref need to be? 1, 2 or both are ok?

Comment: Yes, so someone who has the categories '1' and also '2' in the second filter would appear in a search for '1' or '2' or "'1' and '2'"; someone who only has '2' wouldn't appear, because they don't have both '1' and '2'. Make sense?

Comment: You're using the same field. You cannot do it. A field cannot be on each time 1 and 2 =) that's a trouble, you need to add a field probably, but maybe others have other ideas ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this query

```
SELECT Names FROM all_uk
INNER JOIN cat_uk ON all_uk.Ref = cat_uk.Ref
INNER JOIN res_uk ON all_uk.Ref = res_uk.Ref
WHERE (cat_uk.Cat_Ref IN (25, 35)) 
GROUP BY Names
HAVING SUM(res_uk.Res_Ref = 1)>0
   AND SUM(res_uk.Res_Ref = 2)>0
```

Comment: Beautiful, elegant and simple! Give this man a gold star! Thank you, @Mihai